# Gitlab cicd schedule job check if this already done

Tags: gitlab-ci, schedule

I did scheduled job but it can work several times even if there is no changes(in source ) no commit after it done no mr.
How to check if it worked once end ifthere is no changes don't start it again?

Comment: If you only want to run the job once per change, why use the schedule to begin with? Why not run it on branch pipeline when it is pushed?

Comment: Because changes can come not in right time

Answer (score 1):

One way you might do this is to create/check a `cache:` file to determine if the scheduled pipeline has already run.

If the file does not exist, it means that the schedule job has not run for this commit SHA. If the file *does* exist (is restored from cache), then we know the schedule already ran before on this commit. Here we use a `key:` of `$CI_COMMIT_SHA` so that the cache will be invalidated only when there are changes to the repo.

```yaml
myjob:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"'
  cache:
    key: $CI_COMMIT_SHA
    paths:
      - .schedule_cache
    

  script: 
    - |  # check if the job already ran for this commit
      if [[ -f .schedule_cache ]]; then
          echo "already ran for this commit, nothing to do"
          exit 0
      fi
    - ... # do the job
    - echo "done" > .schedule_cache  # create the cache file
```

If you need this job to run *both* for branches and for schedules, you can change the key to `key: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE-$CI_COMMIT_SHA` so that the key will additionally be separate for each pipeline source.